# MySQL - Create table Column with pre-defined insertacle value

Tags: mysql, create-table

I want to create a table which would have a column named **Role** where only 3 value can be inserted, "Admin","User","Customer".

So, what I have done is this-

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonID int,
    Name varchar(255),
    Role varchar(10) IN ("Admin","User","Customer"),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
)
```

But it is giving me a error like it-

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance for helpipng :)

Comment: You can't be bothered to copy the actual text of the error message in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enum datatype, as following:
Check this url: [enum mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html)

```
CREATE TABLE Person
    (
        PersonID int,
        Name varchar(255),
        Role enum("Admin","User","Customer"),
        Address varchar(255),
        City varchar(255)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you must insert separately

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
PersonID int,
Name varchar(255),
Role varchar(10),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

SQL INSERT INTO Syntax
It is possible to write the INSERT INTO statement in two forms.

The first form does not specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

The second form specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```